# Jmeter - Is it possible to authorize using cookie

Tags: authentication, cookies, jmeter, authorization

The only option I find, is basic authorization. How can I authorize with cookie?

Comment: It's to wide section to wrote about authentication. But yeah You can have for example JWT(Json Web Tokens) stored in cookie section.

Comment: Oh and i don't know about authorize with Jmeter becouse i don't know what is it. XD

Answer (score 0):

It is and it's quite enough to add a [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan. It **automatically** manages cookies, i.e. reads it from previous response and adds to the next request so you shouldn't require anything else.

In some cases you might need to add a cookie manually, you can do this using the aforementioned HTTP Cookie Manager as well.

[image]

The cookies you add manually will be added to the request:

[image]

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response, but for some reason the cookies are not taken. I tried both - just to add the cookie manager and also to add the cookie manually. May be the 'cookie policy' option matters or on which level is the cookie manager set? I set it to Test plan.